# Exporting class imported from another module

Tags: c++, clang++, c++-modules

I am experimenting with C++ modules, using `clang 5.0`, and I am trying to understand how can I export from one module something that I have imported from another module. Is that even possible?

For example, I'd like to have something like this:

```
// root.hehe.cppm
export module root.hehe;

class hehe
{    
};
```

and this:

```
// root.cppm
export module root;

import root.hehe;

export class hehe; // ... doesn't work!
export hehe; // Also doesn't work!
export import root.hehe; // No dice!
```

So that in the end I can do something like

```
import root;

// ...

hehe myhehe;
```

Is such a thing possible? I also tried figuring out if there could be a way to import all the submodules of `root`, like `import root.*`, but that didn't work either.

Comment: By old draft `export module <module>` should work fine. It was changed to `export import <module>` in the new draft. But it's WIP, so...

Answer (score 3):

In C++20 (not whatever prototype version in Clang), you can use either of

```
export using ::hehe;
export using hehe=hehe;
```

to do this, with two caveats:

1. The first form must always use a **qualified** name (because the syntax was introduced long ago to copy names *between* namespaces).
2. You must first be able to **use** the name you imported, which is not the case in your example because `root.hehe` did not export it.  (For the type alias approach, it’s sufficient to be able to name it via `decltype` or so.)

You can also use `export import root.hehe;` to reexport **everything** exported by the module being imported.  There is no wildcard import syntax: module names with dots have **no semantics** whatsoever (in C++20).